# laravel localization set the default locale parameter replacing other parameters

Tags: laravel, laravel-localization

I am new to laravel. when I set the default locale from localization.php and I click on any of my data list edit buttons it replaces the id variable to locale value like (en/ ur/ sd).

then I remove the default locale parameter from Localization.php

ill get Missing parameter: about

web.php

```
Route::group([
    'prefix' => '{locale}', 
    'where' => ['locale' => '[a-zA-Z]{2}'], 
    'middleware' => 'Localization'
    ], function() {


        Route::get('/', function () {
            return redirect(route('home'));
        });
        
Route::resource('/about', AboutController::class)->middleware('auth');
});
```

kernel.php

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'password.confirm' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword::class,
        'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,

        // Permission
        'role' => \Spatie\Permission\Middlewares\RoleMiddleware::class,
        'permission' => \Spatie\Permission\Middlewares\PermissionMiddleware::class,
        'role_or_permission' => \Spatie\Permission\Middlewares\RoleOrPermissionMiddleware::class,
        'Localization' => \App\Http\Middleware\Localization::class,
    ];
```

Localization.php

```
class Localization
{
    /**
    * Handle an incoming request.
    *
    * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
    * @param  \Closure  $next
    * @return mixed
    */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {        

        URL::defaults(['locale' => $request->segment(1)]);
        app()->setLocale($request->segment(1));
        return $next($request);
        
        
    }
}
```

AboutController.php edit function

```
public function edit($id)
    {
       
        $singleRow = About::find($id); 
        $allRows = About::all();
        return view('about', compact('allRows','singleRow'));
    }
```

app.php

```
'locale' => 'en',
'fallback_locale' => 'en',

    'available_locales' => [
         'en',
         'sd',
         'ur',
      ],
```

about.blade.php  Edit section when I click here for edit data

if I try without app()->getLocale() and the locale parameter is assigned from Localization.php
I ll replace the id as selected locale language like en, sd, ur whatever is given in URL like http://127.0.0.1:8000/en/about/1/edit

1st try with default locale parameter mentioned above

```
<a href="{{ route('about.edit', ['about' => $about->id]) }}" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>
```

second try without locale parameter mentioned above

```
<a href="{{ route('about.edit', ['locale'=> app()->getLocale(), 'about' => $about->id]) }}" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>
```

in this time I have set the default locale from Localization.php mentioned above and removed the locale parameter from my tag

```
<a href="{{ route('about.edit', ['about' => $about->id]) }}" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>
```

I get this in my browser when I clicked on edit button

changed return to dd

```
public function edit($id)
    {
       
        dd($id);
        $singleRow = About::find($id); 
        $allRows = About::all();
        return view('about', compact('allRows','singleRow'));

    }
```

[image: image is here]

in this time I commented on the locale parameter from Localization.php and added the locale parameter in my tag

```
<a href="{{ route('about.edit', ['locale'=> app()->getLocale(), 'about' => $about->id]) }}" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Localization.php

```
class Localization
    {
        /**
        * Handle an incoming request.
        *
        * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
        * @param  \Closure  $next
        * @return mixed
        */
        public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
        {        
    
            URL::defaults(['locale' => $request->segment(1)]);
            app()->setLocale($request->segment(1));
            return $next($request);
            
            
        }
    }
```

language switcher where i was getting the error.
in master.blade.php

```
@foreach (config('app.available_locales') as $locale)
            <li class="dropdown messages-menu">
                <a class="nav-link"
                href="{{ route(\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::currentRouteName(), ['locale'=>$locale,0]) }}"
                    @if (app()->getLocale() == $locale) style="font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline" @endif>{{ strtoupper($locale) }}</a>
            </li>
        @endforeach
```

here in master.blade.php i set $locale with ['locale'=> $locale, 0]
i don't know second parameter is why required but its working fine

and i have changed the controller edit function as

```
public function edit($ignore='', $id)
    {
       
        $singleRow = About::find($id); 
        $allRows = About::all();
        return view('about', compact('allRows','singleRow'));
    }
```

here i am getting the id when i click on the edit

```
<a href="{{ route('about.edit', ['about' => $about->id]) }}" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>
```